# pre-fill stdin in C

Tags: c, printf, stdin

My program is supposed to let the user edit a line of a file. The user edits the line and sends it back by pressing enter. Therefore I would like to print the current line which is about to be edited, but kind of print it on stdin instead of stdout.
The only problem I don't know how to solve is how I can prefill the stdin. I've already tried this:

```
char cprefill[] = {"You may edit this line"};
char cbuffer[100];
fprintf(stdin, cprefill);
fgets(cbuffer, 100, stdin);
```

This seems to be the simplest solution, but is probably too simple to work. The fprintf doesn't print anything to stdin. What is the correct way?

Edit:
[image: Result]

This is how it is supposed to look like. Please mind the cursor which can be moved.

Comment: Use a library (ncurses, readline or something like that).

Comment: Interesting Q, but to broad for SO.

Comment: You need to make a distinction between the stdin/stdout buffers and the terminal that captures and presents them.
Just think of your question in terms of files - if stdin is an input file and stdout is an output file, does your question still make sense? Would you like to also capture the backspace key strokes?
What you need is a library that would be compatible with your terminal, like ncurses, or any other.

Comment: Alright, thank you all!

Comment: stdin can be read only and probably in most runs of most programs in the world isn't even a terminal or anything that a user can interact with. So it would be crazy to allow tricks like that. To do what you want to do you need a library for interacting with the full terminal like other comments suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need the libreadline *developer* package. (You might also need the `libreadline` if it's not already available on your system)

On Debian / Ubuntu that's `apt install libreadline-dev` (plus `libreadline6` if you need the binaries also - `6` might be different on your platform)

Then you can add an history to `readline`, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>    

...

char cprefill[] = {"You may edit this line"};

add_history(cprefill);

char *buf = readline("Line: ");

printf("Edited line is %s\n", buf);

// free the line allocated by readline
free(buf);
```

User is prompted "Line: ", and has to do <kbd>UP ARROW</kbd> to get and edit the history, i.e. the `cprefill` line.

Note that you have to compile/link with `-lreadline`

`readline` prints the prompt given as argument, then waits for user interaction, allowing line edition, and arrows to load lines stored in the history.

The `char *` returned by `readline` has then to be freed (since that function allocates a buffer with `malloc()`).

Comment: In this case the user has to read and copy the suggested line. For better usability I would instead like to have it already copied.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The C language has no notion of terminal nor of line edition, so it cannot be done in a portable way. You can either rely on a library like [n]curses to get an almost portable solution, or if you only need that on one single OS use low level OS primitives.

For exemple on Windows, you could feed the input buffer by simulating key strokes into the appropriate window (for example by sending WM_CHAR messages) just before reading, but that would be highly non portable - and in the end is no longer a C but a Windows solution...

Comment: Simulating keystrokes in this case might be highly error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GNU Readline. It calls the function that `rl_startup_hook` points to when starting, where we use `rl_insert_text` to put our text in the line buffer.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

int prefill(void)
{
    rl_insert_text("You may edit this line");

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *cbuffer;

    puts("Please edit the following line");
    rl_startup_hook = prefill;
    if ((cbuffer = readline(NULL)) == NULL) /* if the user sends EOF, readline will return NULL */
        return 1;
    printf("You entered: %s\n", cbuffer);
    free(cbuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

For more information, see the [GNU Readline manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC23).